# Resize a tabular object to textwidth

Tags: tables, scaling

I have a table which its width exceed the textwidth of the document, but I want reduce its size to fit the textwidth space.

I have tried the resizebox command but it doesn't work at all.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{  
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  One & Two &Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten & Eleven &
  Twelve & Thirteen & Fourteen\\

  \hline
  \hline
  $1.111$ & $2.222$ & $3.333$ & $4.444$ & $5.555$ & $6.666$ & $7.777$ &
  $8.888$ & $9.999$ & $0.000$ & $1.111$ & $2.222$ & $3.333$ & $4.444$\\
  \hline  
\end{tabular}
}
  \caption{Test Table}
  \label{tab:label_test}
\end{table}
```

The table keeps the same width and exceed the border of the page. 
I want resize the table, scaling all the tabular object without touch the caption fontsize.

How can I do that?

If I copy the code of @HarishKumar:
[image: Width adjustbox command]

Comment: I think I have a problem with my latex package, because even the solution provided by @HarishKumar doesn't work...

Comment: The problem is that you are always viewing the DVI output. You schould run `pdflatex` and then view the PDF output! DVI viewers cannot show scaling and rotations. Or convert your dvi to pdf if you need that way.

Comment: You are right... thank you very much I was becoming crazy

Comment: Remark for any passer-by: scaling tables should be very low in the list of options. In the sense that one should *never* do it. Reducing the font size with `\small` or `\footnotesize` together with actions on `\tabcolsep` is most of the times sufficient to get by.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`\resizebox` should work provided you put `\usepackage{graphicx}`. But here is a better option with `adjustbox` package. With this, you can resize only if the table goes beyond `\textwidth`, otherwise not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
  \begin{tabular}{*{14}{|c}|}%%{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  One & Two &Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten & Eleven &
  Twelve & Thirteen & Fourteen\\
  \hline
  \hline
  $1.111$ & $2.222$ & $3.333$ & $4.444$ & $5.555$ & $6.666$ & $7.777$ &
  $8.888$ & $9.999$ & $0.000$ & $1.111$ & $2.222$ & $3.333$ & $4.444$\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
  \caption{Test Table}
  \label{tab:label_test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but your solution doesn't work for me, look at my edited question

Comment: @nunzio13n It works. Some thing else is wrong.

Comment: You may want to note that the `\centering` instruction isn't entirely redundant, as it will have an effect in case the natural width of the object contained in `adustbox` is less than `\textwidth`.

Comment: This solution works as long as you _don't_ use [XeLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/XeLaTeX) and hyperlinks in the table. See similar [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368367/adjustbox-with-xelatex-misplaces-hyperlinks).

Comment: that is nice, solved my problem. but with \centering, all section titles and all text in the document somehow centered. After removing \centering, it looks Ok.

Comment: This is amazing! Worked perfectly - thank you!

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Thank you. It has helped me.
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.58\textwidth} %\textwidth
This helped in resizing the text and the box.

Answer (score 16):

you have two unwanted spaces. Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabular}{*{14}{|c}|}%%{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  One & Two &Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten & Eleven &
  Twelve & Thirteen & Fourteen\\\hline\hline
  $1.111$ & $2.222$ & $3.333$ & $4.444$ & $5.555$ & $6.666$ & $7.777$ &
  $8.888$ & $9.999$ & $0.000$ & $1.111$ & $2.222$ & $3.333$ & $4.444$\\\hline
\end{tabular}%
}
  \caption{Test Table}\label{tab:label_test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but even without the spaces, width  the comment character %, the table keeps to exceed the border of the page

Comment: That's not possible with your code! You must do something special. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3):

just put the scale in  before `\textwidth` e.g. `width=0.9\textwidth`.

Comment: Welcome, can you extend your answer a little bit Right now, it is quite short and seems to be more suited as a comment.

Comment: This answer is insufficient, as it needs to be mentioned where to put this command and the effect. if set in wrong place, it just shrinks the table without shrinking the content.

Comment: thanks this works

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with max width with `0.9` or `0.7`. It shrinks the table further.

For e.g., `\begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.77\textwidth}`

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}   %% just for demo
\begin{document}
    \tiny
    \begin{table}[h]
         \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ %   
            \begin{tabular}{*{14}{|l|{0.6cm}}}%%{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
                One & Two &Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten & Eleven &
                Twelve & Thirteen & Fourteen\\\hline\hline
                1.111 & 2.222 & 3.333 & 4.444 & 5.555 & 6.666 & 7.777 &
                8.888 & 9.999 & 0.000 & 1.111 & 2.222 & 3.333 & 4.444\\\hline
            \end{tabular}
    %   }       
        \caption{Test Table}\label{tab:label_test}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

enter image description here.

I have removed all `$` signs. They are not needed. I have set all columns to 0.6 cm. I have put `\begin{table}[h]` so that table begins at this height.

Comment: Your MWE contain error. Please correct it.