# Import and scale LaTeX table data from file (only ampersand stuff)

Tags: tables, input

Is it possible to create a table and include only the pure data from an external file (only ampersand delimited stuff). Is it also possible to scale a table because data is vast and I don't want to keep on messing with table width and heights??

```
\begin{table}[H!]   
\centering  
\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\input{stuff};
\end{tabular}   
\caption{This is a caption} 
\label{xxxx}    
\end{table}
```

I want to import the data on the \input{stuff} part

Comment: Use braces not parentheses.  That is `\input{stuff}`.

Comment: This question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163246/resize-a-tabular-object-to-textwidth addresses the issue of rescaling tabular material to `\textwidth`.

Comment: With braces (as edited), it should work just fine.

Comment: Since the import problem is evidently solved, I vote to close as a duplicate of the scaling question linked above.