# Resize DIA-generated graphics

Tags: graphics, resize

Is there a way to create a diagram in Dia,

- output to intermediate vector graphics, and
- resize the resultant graphics in the page?

Obviously, the png export works with `\includegraphics`, but that result is pixeled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying several failing options

- pstricks export, which failed to work properly with pdflatex
- tikz output with `\include` and resizebox,

the following works:

1. Output your diagram as "LaTeX pgf macros (.tex)"
2. [Create a `\begin{adjustbox}` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/163250/90454) (with the `\usepackage{adjustbox}` header)
3. [`\input`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44482/90454) the file into this environment (you could also copy-paste the contents), adding the `\usepackage{tikz}` header

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) export with `pdflatex`, you have to:

1) load [`auto-pst-pdf`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf) (*after* pstricks)

2) Launch pdflatex with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `--shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX).

Comment: Thank you. Does this resize automatically?