# \adjustbox with XeLaTeX misplaces hyperlinks

Tags: xetex, positioning, links, latexmk, adjustbox

This is minimal (not) working example that comes from much bigger document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\hreftt[2]{%
    \href{#1}{\texttt{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\rubylink}{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)}{Ruby}}
\newcommand{\erlanglink}{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)}{Erlang}}
\newcommand{\pythonlink}{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)}{Python}}
\newcommand{\powershelllink}{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell}{PowerShell}}
\begin{table}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
        Programming language & \rubylink         & \rubylink, \erlanglink  & \pythonlink, \powershelllink  & \pythonlink           \\\hline
        Something            & aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbb           & ccccccccccccc                 & dddddddddddddddddddd
    \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
    \caption{This is test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it with the command `latexmk -pdf` it produces correct PDF:

[image: Correct output]

But when I compile with [XeLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/XeLaTeX), like that: `latexmk -pdf -pdflatex=xelatex` it produces:

[image]

Unfortunately I need to use [XeLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/XeLaTeX) and the above example needs to produce correct PDF. How can I fix misplaced hyperlinks?

Comment: I think this has come up before (scaling pdf links is tricky) but scaling tables should only be a last resort, is there really no alternative?

Comment: I have 5-columns table with comparison of some software. Unfortunately this table is (a little bit) too wide to fit `\textwidth`. On the one hand too wide table looks ugly, but on the other hand, as @Ulrike Fischer [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/368385/44382), scaling a tabular is bad typesetting.

Comment: yes but you would not justify a paragraph of text by applying arbitrary scale so having inconsistent fonts and spacing, so why do it to the text if it is in a `tabular` ?  It should always be possible to use `\small` or reduce `\tabcolsep` or some other way of adjusting the table.

Comment: I've changed table's font to [`\footnotesize`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc) and it looks much better now. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scaling a tabular is bad typesetting. It leads to uneven font sizes.

Your problem is due to a change in xetex.def which broke skaling of link areas. This problem affects a current texlive 2016, texlive 2017 pretest and a current miktex.

As a workaround until the problem is resolved you can try to revert to the older definition by adding to your document.

```
\makeatletter
\def\Gscale@start{%
  \special{x:gsave}\special{x:scale \Gscale@x\space\Gscale@y}}
\makeatletter
```

You can also use tikz instead as it scales links area when xelatex is used correctly (it doesn't with pdflatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}\parskip1cm
\newcommand{\rubylink}{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)}{Ruby}}

abc \rubylink cde

\scalebox{2}{abc \rubylink cde}

\tikz[scale=2,transform shape]\node[inner sep=0]{abc \rubylink cde};

\end{document}
```

[image]